# How to configure Grub for Android-x86

Tags: debian, grub, android, android-x86

I have: Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie) installed on old Gygabyte laptop.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5250  @ 1.50GHz
```

2 Gb RAM.

I successfully installed and run android-x86-2.3-RC1-eeepc.iso on VirtualBox.
However I don't have vt-x | amd-v support and virtualization is SUPER slow.
I installed official Java emulator of Android and it was evem MORE SUPER SLOW.
Now I try install Android on my HD for dual boot.
I have Grub: 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1
I try to install android-x86-4.4-r5.iso image on /dev/sda3.

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 267446271 267444224 127.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       267651072 308406271  40755200  19.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       308408318 312580095   4171778     2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       308408320 312580095   4171776     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I mount it and this what I have:

```
root@olgacomp:/media/olga# tree -L 3
.
└── Android-x86
    ├── android-4.4-r5
    │   ├── data
    │   ├── initrd.img
    │   ├── kernel
    │   ├── ramdisk.img
    │   └── system
    └── lost+found
```

When I reboot my computer, I don't see Android option in Grub list.
I know that new grub doesn't have clear config file.
I'm afraid reinstall Android with Grub installation, because all MBR can be lost.

How can I configure Grub for load new Android installation?
And another question: is there other options for emulate/install Android on old devise without VT-X support if this option will not work?

Comment: OK, so an answer is here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/481982/add-android-x86-4-4-rc2-to-ubuntu-grub It solves my problem )